# ScrollReveal.js is not working in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to animate text in wordpress theme by ScrollReveal.js. It has worked fine in any other webpage, But it is not working in wordpress theme. Please help

Index.php file

```
    <div class="profile-desc"><h2>The title</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

functions.php file

```
    function myblog_resources()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome_style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.min.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('scrollreveal_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/scrollreveal.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'2.0.5',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main_script2', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('main1_script3', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main1.js');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myblog_resources' );
```

javascript file

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('.profile-desc',{
    duration:2000,
    origin:'bottom',
    distance: '300px'
});
```